# looping through nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays, actually a series of table rows.

```
0: Array[5]
0: ""
1: ""
2: "Is there at least one teacher or other adult in this school that you can talk to if you have a problem?"
3: ""
4: ""

1: Array[5]
0: ""
1: ""
2: "Yes"
3: "No"
4: "Not sure"

2: Array[5]
0: "Grade"
1: "6th"
2: "55%"
3: "20%"
4: "25%"
```

If I encounter certain contents, ie a "?" I want to assign that row to a new JSON object. I'm looping through the arrays with forEach loops like this:

```
function parseRow(element, index, array) {
    element.forEach(parseCell);
  }
function parseCell(element, index, array) {
    if (element.indexOf("?") > -1) { // if it is a question
      //do something to tell indicate this is a question row

    }  else { 
      // table cell
    }
  }
```

I need to be more explicit in my goal. I have an array of row values(as arrays), some of which contain a table-defining question, some of which are header rows, and some of which are table rows. I want to spit out a JSON Object formatted something like this:

```
 {
"question": "Is there at least...",
"Category": "Overall",
"Division" : "All",
"Yes" : "65.00%",
"No": "11.70%",
"Not Sure" : "23.30%",
},
{
"question": "Is there at least...",
"Category" : "Grade",
"Division" : "6th",
"Yes" : "65.00%",
"No": "11.70%",
"Not Sure" : "23.30%",
},
{
"question": "Is there at least...",
"Category" : "Grade",
"Division" : "7th",
"Yes" : "65.00%",
"No": "11.70%",
"Not Sure" : "23.30%",
},
```

The JSON object could be more nested, this just seems to be the easiest to deal build.

Comment: If you want to keep `forEach` loops, you need a common closure for both. Alternatively, use `map` and then you can indeed return something processed into a form that `parseRow` can use.

Comment: I'm with @BartekBanachewicz. What **specifically** do you want to do when encountering a `?` character?

Comment: when encounter the "?" I want to assign the element to a newObj {"question": element}, but I also want to make it a marker for a new table. @JonathanBrooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map function that can return objects in order to get an array of questions from you elements array:

```
function parseRow(element, index, array) {
   var questions = element.map(function(el,i){
       if(el.indexOf("?") > -1){
          return el;
       }
   });
}
```

And this will give you an array of elements that contain a question.

Comment: thanks, I'm accepting answer because it answers the basic question, thanks